# Google Product Forums › Google Analytics › Number inflation issue in tracking referral and direct traffic to PDF files via the API

Tags: pdf, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, measurement-protocol

I was hoping you could help me with this. We are attempting to track PDFs for a client, but what we are looking to capture is not PDF link clicks (we're already tracking this just fine!), but referral or direct traffic to PDFs. For instance if the PDF shows up in Google search we want to be able to track if someone clicked on the PDF and opened it.

Using the API we have partially achieved this, but we are seeing drastically inflated numbers for this event - far more than could be reasonably believed. I suspect that the issue is related to bots/crawlers; however when I look at the referral traffic I see either that for the most inflated numbers the referrer is (direct) or Google. Theoretically because we're collecting the referral data shouldn't bots/crawlers be excluded anyway? Is there something I'm missing?

We are using Google Tag Manager and Universal Analytics.

Here are the variables we're setting.

- v – Google version -> “1”
- tid – The Google Analytics ID for the client.
- cid – A random number to make client requests unique.
- t – Event hit type (set to “event”)
- ec – Event category (set to “PDF Activity”)
- ea – Event action. “direct download” if the Url Referrer is null, otherwise “external download”.  Perhaps we should change this to null
  or empty?
- el – Event label. (set to the Raw URL of the request).
- uip – User’s IP Address. The user host address of the request.
- ua – User agent. Set to the user agent of the request.
- dr – Set to the original string for the Url Referrer.?

And here's the corresponding code (C# ASP.NET):

```cs
var data = new NameValueCollection()
{
    {"v", "1"}, // Version.
    {"tid", _googleAnalyticsClientId}, // Tracking ID / Web property / Property ID.
    {"cid", Math.Round(2147483647 * n).ToString()}, // Anonymous Client ID.
    {"t", "event"}, // Event hit type
    {"ec", "PDF Activity"}, // Event Category. Required.
    {"ea", labelValue}, // Event Action. Required.
    {"el", label}, // Event label.

    // The following two parameters are needed for Proxy servers.
    // See: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#using-a-proxy-server

    {"uip", context.Request.UserHostAddress}, // User IP Address
    {"ua", context.Request.UserAgent}, // User's User Agent
    {"dr", context.Request.UrlReferrer != null ? context.Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString: String.Empty}
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How are you tiggering this, using HTTP log's ? - If so then you might not be able to cookie the session to be able to separate the sessions to get unique pageviews. As you said bots/crawlers will also get his by this.